# dB SPL Calculation is not making sense- values are seemingly too high

Tags: measurement, microphone, sound, electret

I am using an electret with a sensitivity of -38.44 dBV to make sound measurements at a distance of 1m. I decided to add an amplification circuit with a gain of 125. So in the end to convert to SPL, I first used my sensitivity which is 11.967mV/Pa (in SI units) to convert the measured voltage to pressure. P=V/S, where V is the voltage before amplification (i.e. output value divide by 125) and S is sensitivity. In the final step, I then convert this to dB SPL using a reference pressure of 20e-6 Pa and the formula dB SPL=20log(Pa_rms/Pref). However, with this formula, I get values ranging around 100 dB, I believe that I am supposed to be getting values around half that, what I am doing wrong? any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Microphone data sheet please.

Comment: I don't follow. -38.44dBV in volts gives 94dB SPL which is 1Pa.The gain of 125 is 41.94 dB. Which means, 3.5dBV still is 94dB SPL. So after gain, with 1.496V you get 1Pa which is 94dB SPL.

Comment: Hi, please clarify what you mean from that part of 3.5 dBV, how did you arrive at that value?, as well as the 1.496 V

Comment: 41.94 - 38.44 = 3.5dBv = 1.496V all at 1Pa = 94dBSPL. So you must be seeing about 3V rms after your amplifier, since you get 100dB, right?

Comment: Okay, let me do this. Lets pick one of the values I measured. Say 4.95 Vrms, which is 0.04 V preamplification, the method m using involves converting such a value to pressure (Pa) using P=V/S, this gives 3.34 Pa using this method. So since the 11.967mV/Pa sensitivity value implies 94 dB, its like any value above the sensitivity will produce values way higher than 94 dB which does not make sense as 94 dB is already an SPL of a heavy truck at 1m.

Comment: Just to give you an idea as to why I am not expecting these values to be very high, I was measuring sound from inside a completely sealed ip65 thermoplastic enclosure. I was using buzzers and speakers to make the sound.

Comment: This is the link to the microphone datasheet. https://www.mantech.co.za/Datasheets/Products/MDO9765.pdf

Comment: "inside a completely sealed enclosure" next to a (piezo?) buzzer... Measure the same microphone in free space about 1m from the buzzer. I'm willing to bet you get levels at least 40dB lower.

Answer (score 0):

The sensitivity is measured at 1m distance, in free space.

In free space, for each halving of distance, sound amplitude goes up by 6dB. So 94 dB at 1m will be 100dB at 50cm, 106dB at 25cm, 112dB at 12.5cm, etc.

Also, the microphone is not measuring in free space, but in a sealed enclosure, so expect higher amount of sound pressure to couple from buzzer to microphone than in free space.